Interchanging order of arbitrary unions
Suppose I define
$$B=\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{k\in J_i}B_k$$
Here $I$ and $J_i$ may be countable or uncountable index sets. Now let me define
$$J=\bigcup_{i\in I}J_i$$
Now, what I want to do is to change the order of union, so I want to find $I_j$ such that I can write
$$B=\bigcup_{j\in J}\bigcup_{k\in I_j}B_k$$
where
$$I=\bigcup_{j\in J}I_j$$
Now this seems completely intuitive however I am unable to construct such $I_j$ from above, neither am I able to show that such a $I_j$ will always exist. Please help me in proving that such a construction always exist, otherwise give a counter example to show that it is not always possible.

The notation $J=\bigcup_{i\in J_i}$ makes no sense. Did you mean to write $J=\bigcup_{i\in I} J_i$? Also, please use MathJax formatting rather than embedding images: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

@AlexKruckman Sorry for that, I have made the correction now. I am finding difficulty in using latex.

User ultralegend5385 kindly formatted your post for you. Please take a look at what they did and use MathJax in your future questions.

Well, if $J=\bigcup_{i\in J} J_i$, then already $$\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{k\in J_i} B_k=\bigcup_{j\in J} B_j,$$ so we've written the double union as a single union. No "interchange" necessary!
If you insist on writing it as a double union, you could define $I_j=\{j\}$ for all $j$ or $I_j=J$ for all $j$. Either way, you'll have $$\bigcup_{j\in J} B_j=\bigcup_{j\in J}\bigcup_{k\in I_j} B_k.$$
